# Decimal to binary - Why can't left and right sides of decimal place be converted to binary as if both sides were integers?

Tags: floating-point

0.2 cannot be represented in floating point because the conversion of 0.2 to binary is repeating. But why cant the right side of the decimal just be treated as an integer when converting to binary? I.e. 0.2 would be 0.10 in binary because 0 would convert to 0 and 2 would convert to 10?

Comment: To get the same value, you would have to treat that as being divided by 10, not a power of two.

Comment: I do not follow. To get what same value? Divide what by 10? Can you elaborate a bit more please.

Comment: Well, you just described that representation, so it can be done. But it is not necessarily a smart representation. For example `0.1100011` and `0.1100100` seem close, but with your convention, one means `0.99` and the other means the much smaller number `0.100` in decimal (that is "zero point ninety-nine" versus "zero point one hundred"). I would say smarter representations of decimally based numbers are known.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your notation, or maybe you are reinventing binary coded decimal. Could you give some more examples? Give the principles behind your notation?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen what if you made the tweak of removing the trailing zeros for the right side before converting it?

Comment: You cannot treat the fraction portion as a simple decimal numeral because you need to distinguish .2 from .02 and .002. Additionally, the fraction portion of 1/3 is .33333…, so it cannot be represented as a finite integer, so a system like this would still have to round numbers to something representable.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil yeah I see that but I feel like along with discarding trailing zeros, you can just keep a count of the leading zeros (for the fractional portion). So 0.02 and 0.002 would be converted the same way just the leading zeros in front of the two would need to be stored. 0.3333 is repetitive in decimal and binary but the purpose of this system would be to make numbers like 0.1, which are finite in decimal, finite in binary as well.

Comment: If you have a system for dealing with the fraction part, you don't need to handle the integer part separately. Just normalize so that e.g. the most significant non-zero digit is immediately to the right of the decimal point, and keep a signed count of how many places you had to shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing seems close to some floating point systems such as Java's [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). It stores numbers as the combination of an integer and a decimal scale factor.

That sort of system is useful if exact representation of decimal fractions is especially important. That is, if exact representation of 1/5 is much more important than exact representation of 1/3.

The big advantage of binary floating point is that it can give a very compact representation that lends itself to hardware arithmetic and register storage.

Comment: Ah interesting I was not aware of this class is it only specific to Java? Also what do you mean by exact representation of 1/3? Even in floating point that is not possible is it?

Comment: @fahimg23 java.math.BigDecimal is java-specific, but a lot of programming languages have something similar for exact representation of decimal fractions. There are also rational number packages that can represent the ratio of any pair of integers, including 1/5 and 1/3. If you need both to be exact, use one of those, if you are OK with rounding 1/3 but not with rounding 1/5, use a decimal data type. If you are OK with rounding error on both, use double.